# what is the meaning of this FOL sentence?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

This FOL sentence is

$$∀x, y (\operatorname{Country}(x) ∧ \operatorname{Country}(y) ∧ \operatorname{Borders}(x, y)) \implies \operatorname{MapColor}(x = y)$$

mean *No two adjacent countries have the same map color* ? Right or wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `MapColor(x) = MapColor(y)`?

Comment: How did you come up with "no" when there is no negation in the sentence? As it is writtne, the sentence means "All two adjacent countries have the same map color".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making $3$ alterations to your suggestion: $$∀x, y [\operatorname{Country}(x) ∧ \operatorname{Country}(y) ∧ \operatorname{Borders}(x, y) ∧ x\ne y \implies [\operatorname{MapColor}(x)\ne\operatorname{MapColor}(y)]]$$ translates to "No two adjacent countries have the same map color".

Comment: You also need: ∧ ¬(=) in the antecedent

Comment: Thanks; edited.